# Installed Node + vue-cli on AWS. But get a blank page?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, vue.js

Ok, learning here. Installed the default vue-cli app on AWS. I do a npm run build. When I launch the default index.html I'm served a blank page. If I go into dist, there is another index.html, that serves links to js files, but still a blank page.

I'm guessing webpack wants me to launch an index.html, but don't see how I can hit that with a browser.  No errors anywhere. But no Hello World either. thanks for help.

What I'm seeing in the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8><title>hello-world</title><link href=/static/css/app.87e65e7c83fb67c04e58d4461a7fd8e8.css rel=stylesheet></head><body><div id=app></div><script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.fa7eecfb52900d1cfb0a.js></script><script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.9baeef453ba99a70f46a.js></script><script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.cdfbb21001bbc43de4bc.js></script></body></html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `npm run build` Webpack should produce an `index.html` file along with a `static/` directory that contains all of your javascript and css. The link to `static/` is an absolute link (i.e. `http://example.org/static`). When you try to open `index.html` as a file, the browser will look for the `/static/` folder on the root of your file system, which of course it won't find.

To run it locally you need to fire up an http server locally. One option is to `cd` into the directory with a terminal app and run `python -m http.server`. Then go to `http://localhost:8000/`. That should work because the root of the directory tree will be the folder from where you are serving it.

Getting it running on AWS S3 will be a matter of making sure you get the static directory in the right place and get the links pointing to it. Hard to say exactly how without knowing details of how you are organizing the site in your bucket.

You can change how the static folder is saved in the webpack config if you need to: https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html

Comment: Awesome explanation, thanks. If have a tip on AWS. Default, barebones EC2 instance is my configuration. Zero changes.

Comment: Not really sure what you'll have on a barebones EC2 instance. Is there a web server running? If so you should be able to put the index.html and the static folder in the root directory. It should be easy to serve from S3 too if it's just a vue app with no backend requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You will find a folder named **/dist** in your project directory.Just point the **index.html** file within the **/dist** directory and rest will work fine I think. I have just done that and it's working fine.
Hope it will work.
Thanks.